# Cannot establish a connection to database using JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, netbeans-8

I cannot figure out why this keeps popping whenever I am trying to set up a new connection.

My school project requires to connect netbeans to a database.

I've been following this video tutorial: [How to Connect Netbeans to Microsoft Access Database by Kindson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FABD-q13YTo) .

and after learning that SE 8 does not have `jdbc:odbc` bridge. Then, I found this tutorial: [How to enable JDBC-ODBC bridge for JDK 8](https://bigfatball.blogspot.it/2016/03/how-to-enable-jdbc-odbc-bridge-for-jdk-8.html)

> cannot establish a connection to jdbc:odbc:test database using
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver (null)

So at the moment I'm at this part knowing nothing of whats wrong ([Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFdz6.png)).

Comment: *"my school project requires me to connect netbeans to a database"* - Does it have to be an *Access* database?

Comment: no, but i will need a new tutorial related to what database your gonna recommend

like save/load data to that database, etc.

Comment: If you really want to connect to MS Access with Java 8, I would recommend looking at this library http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.healthmarketscience.jackcess/jackcess/2.1.6 as it does not depend on jdbc:odbc bridge

Comment: @i.net - [UCanAccess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390) would probably be easier than Jackcess for a relative newbie to work with.

Comment: @GordThompson I'll take your word for this as it's been a long time since I interacted with Access and my experience is limited to Jackcess (wasn't too pleasant but not too bad either)

Comment: thx, ill try that but heh, i doubt i can install those at school

Comment: If your school has issues with you installing a JDBC driver then chances are good that they also wouldn't take kindly to you hacking JRE8 to include the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. If they have already made a JDBC driver available to you then they should tell you what it is.

Comment: heres the "thing", lazy teacher, writes a do this "activity", then sits, does nothing for the entire class and we all simply scramble what we can find at youtube for a tutorial